# Why sounds not working properly in my laptop?

Tags: 20.04, dell, alsa, 22.04

I have a earphone(fine) and a new laptop dell inspiron-3501 with ubuntu 20.04. But I have a audio problem. Speakers are working fine but earphones are not working.

When I plugin earphone then the laptop does not recognize earphone. But in alsamixer if I increase the volume up of headphone then sound in earphone works but speakers also plays simultaneously along with earphone. Also next time alsamixer always has volume 0 for headphones.

**UPDATE:** I just upgraded to ubuntu 22.04LTS with kernel 5.15.0-25-generic but the problem remains the same.

This is my alsamixer screenshot.

[image]

dell inspiron-3501 Hardware specs:

```
Processor: 11th Generation Intel Core i5
RAM: 8 gb
Audio: Cirrus Logic CS8409/CS42L42 
Storage: 256 GB SSD
GPU: Integrated Intel Iris Xe Graphics
```

Comment: 11th gen Intel CPUs are better supported with newer kernel. Which one are you running on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @ChanganAuto i am using `5.13.0-35-generic`

Comment: Make and model of your headphones that aren't working is more important than the model of your laptop speakers that are working.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i thought speakers were working fine but later i found that speakers are not working properly also. Strange issue sometimes they work and sometimes they don't and some cracking sounds appears sometime.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix speaker doesn't work after screen lock, i need to reboot laptop again then it works.

Comment: @D_P After unlocking screen, open terminal and type `pulseaudio -k` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: didn't worked @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i've updated my question can you please check that ?

Comment: @D_P See this for some clues: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=205759

Comment: Your sound chip is supported in kernel 5.15

Comment: upgraded to ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15 but the issue remains same

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Settings > Sound > Output Device and select the device you want to use.